# How to get sum of column values for each row in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

How can i get sum of column values for each row and push each row's total in rowTotalArray.

[Image is Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYimo.png)

The number of rows and input fields are dynamic. When user enters number in input field for each column in row , last column (Total) must show sum of column value for each row.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';

function RowWiseSum() {
    const datas = useSelector(state => state.dataList.datas);
   
    const [group, setGroup] = useState([{
        g1: 0,
        g2: 0,
        g3: 0,
    }]);

    const [sum, setSum] = useState(0);
    const [rowTotalArray, setRowTotalArray] = useState([]); 
  
    useEffect(() => {
        let sum = parseFloat(group.g1) + parseFloat(group.g2) + parseFloat(group.g3);
       setSum(sum);
    }, [group])

    return (
        <Table striped bordered size="sm" style={{ fontSize: '12px' }}>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sn</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>No. in G1</th>
                    <th>No. in G2</th>
                    <th>No. in G3</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {
                   datas.map((data, i) => 
                    (
                        <tr key={i}>
                            <td>{data.sno}</td>
                            <td>{data.description}</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type='text' name={`g1-${i+1}`} onChange={(e) => setGroup({ ...group, g1: e.target.value })} />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type='text'  name={`g2-${i+1}`}   onChange={(e) => setGroup({ ...group, g2: e.target.value })} />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type='text'  name={`g3-${i+1}`} onChange={(e) => setGroup({ ...group, g3: e.target.value })} />
                            </td>
                    
                            <td>
                                <input type='text' readOnly value={sum} name={`sum-${i+1}`} />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        
                    ))
                }
            </tbody>
        </Table>
    )
}
export default RowWiseSum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your group state should be array of each row point, so you can caculate total of each row

```
const defaultGroup = datas.map((i) => ({
  g1: 0,
  g2: 0,
  g3: 0
}));
const [group, setGroup] = useState(defaultGroup);
const onChange = (type, value, index) => {
  const newGroup = group.map((g, idx) => {
    if (index === idx)
      return {
        ...g,
        [type]: parseInt(value || 0)
      };
    return g;
  });
  setGroup(newGroup);
};

const total = group.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc += cur.g1 + cur.g2 + cur.g3;
  return acc;
}, 0);
return (
  <div className="App">
    <table striped bordered size="sm" style={{ fontSize: "12px" }}>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Sn</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>No. in G1</th>
          <th>No. in G2</th>
          <th>No. in G3</th>
          <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {datas.map((data, i) => (
          <tr key={i}>
            <td>{data.sno}</td>
            <td>{data.description}</td>
            <td>
              <input
                type="number"
                name={`g1-${i + 1}`}
                defaultValue={group[i].g1}
                onChange={(e) => onChange("g1", e.target.value, i)}
              />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input
                type="number"
                name={`g2-${i + 1}`}
                defaultValue={group[i].g2}
                onChange={(e) => onChange("g2", e.target.value, i)}
              />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input
                type="number"
                name={`g3-${i + 1}`}
                defaultValue={group[i].g3}
                onChange={(e) => onChange("g3", e.target.value, i)}
              />
            </td>

            <td>
              <input
                type="text"
                readOnly
                name={`sum-${i + 1}`}
                value={group[i].g1 + group[i].g2 + group[i].g3}
              />
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>TOTAL: {total}</div>
  </div>
);
```

I've created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-surf-cesckj?file=/src/App.js:89-2234), you can check it. Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

your group state should be like this
 `const [group, setGroup] = useState({ g1: 0, g2: 0, g3: 0, });`

instead of
`const [group, setGroup] = useState([{g1: 0, g2: 0, g3: 0,}])`